# Forgot MySQL password

Tags: mysql, password

Today I realized that I forgot the MySQL password, or that somebody else changed it (I doubt it).

Is there any possibility that I can get the root password?

I have access to all the machine (as it's mine), don't think that I'm trying to hack into someone else database or w/e.

I'm desperate, I've trying with a lot of different passwords, no luck so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart MySQL with `skip-grant-tables` in your config, change the password, then restart again after taking `skip-grant-tables` back out.

Oh, and if you have an internet exposed MySQL listener (which you really shouldn't), then you need to change that (`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`) before you do this.